# difference between *b= *b+1 and *b++

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

I am trying to change the actual value of a and b in the main function. But when I use *b++ to increment the value of b. It is not working.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int F(int *b,int *c ){
    *b++;
    *c++;

}
int main(){
    int a=1 , b=2;
    cout<<a<<" "<< b<<" ";
    F(&a, &b);

    cout<<a<<" "<< b;
}
```

but in 2nd Case, the code is working fine.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int F(int *b,int *c ){
    *b = *b+1;
    *c = *c+1;

}
int main(){
    int a=1 , b=2;
    cout<<a<<" "<< b<<" ";
    F(&a, &b);

    cout<<a<<" "<< b;
}
```

Isn't *b++ and *b=*b+1 same?

Answer (score 7):

They are not the same, the first expression is just manipulating your pointer due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

```
*b++;     // acts like *(b++)
```

This increments the pointer, then dereferences it. You need extra parentheses

```
(*b)++;
```

Answer (score 5):

Per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

`++` has higher precedence than `*b`, so `*b++` is `*(b++)`

`+` has lower precedence than `*b` so `*b+1` is `(*b) + 1`